# Setting up Aquila for my c++ Project in Visual studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I want to use [Aquila DSP](http://aquila-dsp.org/) to compute MFCC features in my project and trying to make it work.I followed [this tutorial](http://nip-saga.blogspot.de/2015/06/configure-aquila-digital-signal-processing-libraray-visual-studio.html) but after `mingw32-make install` on the source code pulled from Aquila's git repo, it generates only `libAquila.a` in lib folder. I tried changing my project's include and library dependencies using these generated files after install. Also tried adding `FindAquila.cmake` and tried building my project with cmake for VS 2012, still no luck. Keep getting `"aquila/global.h" no such file or directory` when I try to include `"aquila/global.h"`.

I also tried building Aquila with cmake for VS 2012 and able to compile it and it generates .lib files as well, but not sure how to proceed with that.

If anyone knows how to make it work, it will be great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I made it work with Visual studio 2013. Now what I am doing is I am building Aquila with both Mingw and with VisualStudio. Mingw gives required include files and visual studio build gives required .lib files. I am building Aquila in VS 2013 with configuration type static lib (`project properties >> General >> Configuration type`) for both debug and release configuration and then I build the project.

For Mingw, first I use cmake GUI with `mingw cmakefiles` configuration and then run `mingw32-make install` in the build directory, which will put the include, lib and share files in the installation directory( usually `C:\\Programme files\\Aquila`.

Now I create a Folder `Aquila` and put `include` and `share` from above path and create a new folder `lib` with two subfolder `debug` and `release`. Here I put two .lib files in each folder (`aquila.lib and Ooura_fft.lib`) (debug libs in debug and release libs in release folder, they will be VS build folder). Once this is done, in my project setting, I add Additional include directories under `C++ >> general`, Addiotnal library path under `linker >> general` and names of libraries under `linker >> input` for both bebug and release configuration. After doing all these things, now the library works with my project.