# How use Aquila library in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, signal-processing

I want to know about [Aquila library](http://aquila-dsp.org/) and use the library for Signal Processing applications. How can I add and use Aquila library in C++ Visual Studio 2013?

Can anyone please explain how to implement this library in C++?

Comment: Why not read the doc and example of the library?

Comment: @Mine I read doc but i want know how can i add it to my project

Comment: Check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37618690/setting-up-aquila-for-my-c-project-in-visual-studio-2012. Maybe help You.